# no output displays after proper configuration of reactjs webpack, package.json

Tags: reactjs

After setting up of my reactjs environment, my first hello world does not display the proper output.

This is the output after successfully compiled
[output after successfully compiled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWhef.png)

//This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "reactjs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.1"
  }
}
```

//This is my webpack.config.js file

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require('webpack');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {

    mode: 'development',
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },

    performance: {
    hints: false
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

// this is my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<p>hello, my name is Oldrick</p>, 
    document.getElementById('firstapp')
);
```

//this is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="firstapp"></div>
    <script type="/app/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you make any babel config file?

Comment: You are using webpack 4 so you don't need to add entry point webpack automatically compile your index.js file in the src directory.